# Home Automation w/ Z-wave - config via UI?

Tags: home-automation

I know this is a bit of an oxymoron but is there an app out there for Z-wave automation that will let me configure devices and rules from the GUI instead of the config file? I'm currently using Home Assistant but a bit cumbersome having to edit config files every time I want to create an event.  Looks like openhab would be similar. Any other good ones out there?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you mean, but NodeRed is a nice way to visually program events. It supports zwave and mqtt, so it can certainly integrate with hass.